# New to python and attempting to webscrape a table that refreshes every 15 min. Getting an error about needing a string

Tags: python, web-scraping

Error:

C:\Python>python webscrape.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscrape.py", line 23, in 
    print ("hubs:" + hubs)
TypeError: must be str, not list

Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'http://www.ercot.com/content/cdr/html/real_time_spp'

# opening up connection, grabbing the web page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grabs the market conditions
intervals = page_soup.findAll("div",{"id":"today"})

for interval in intervals:
    hubs = interval.table.tr.th["class"]

    price_intervals = interval.findAll("td",{"class":"labelClassCenter"})
    all_prices = price_intervals[0].text

    print ("hubs:" + hubs)
    print ("all_prices:" + all_prices)
```

Comment: Yeah, the error is very descriptive itself...hubs is a list so you can't show it's content like that....if you for example, write `print("Hubs:" + hubs[0])`, you are going to get one result...or you can use `join`, like `print("Hubs: " + hubs.join(","))`

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate them with a comma, not concatenate them:

```
print("hubs:", hubs)
```

You’re getting the same warning as this:

```
>>> print("hi" + [1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    print("hi" + [1])
TypeError: must be str, not list
>>> print("hi", [1])
hi [1]
```

With the plus sign you are trying to concatenate (or put together) the string and the list. If you want to do that, you have to make the list a string:

```
>>> print("hi" + str([1]))
hi[1]
```

If you want to separate the values by commas, do `','.join(hubs)`.

Note: If you are using Python 2, you don’t need the parentheses in the print statement.

Another way to do it is with string formatting:

```
print(“hubs: {hubs}”.format(hubs=hubs))
```

Comment: If you’re using python2 instead of python3, you also probably don’t want the parentheses in the print statement.

Comment: @DanielH It looks like he’s using python 3 because of the parentheses in his print statement.

Comment: Yes, but from the question and being new to Python, that’s not a guarantee. When I was first learning python (2), I often put parentheses in accidentally because that’s how other programming languages (and most other operations in Python) work.

Comment: For Python 3, the superior `str.format()` would be worth considering as well: `print("hubs: {0}".format(hubs))`